# Javascript/Prototype: Get css values, without referencing DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, css, prototypejs

Is it possible to retrieve a style property by class name (e.g width of a class), defined in a CSS file, without having to fetch it from an actual element in the DOM?

Comment: Very interesting question... Waiting for answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible, but more complicated.
You have access to stylesheets with the `document.styleSheets` property.

Within each stylesheet you have to access to the [cssRules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRuleList) property that contains all the CSS rules in that stylesheet, so to get the first rule in the first stylesheet in the DOM you can do

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0];
```

To find a certain element you have to parse the stylesheet, and this is where it get's complicated in some cases, as styles are inherited etc. but if looking for a certain selector and a certain style :

```
var rules = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules,
    theRule = null;

for (var i=0; i<rules.length; i++) {
     if (rules[i].selectorText.toLowerCase() == '#myelement') {
         var width = rules[i].style.width;
         break;
     }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing there's no way to select a CSS by name from the list, other than iterating and matching the name in the href, correct?

Comment: @Dror - There actually is, `rules[i].selectorText` gets the selector text, such as `#elementID` or `.class:hover` etc. It should be noted that accessing the stylesheets like this is generally a bad idea, and hard to get right.

Comment: I was referring to the name of a css file, is that what you meant as well?

Comment: Oh no, you can't access the stylesheets by name, then you'd have the get the link tags, and check the href, and find the position in the DOM etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Check out the `document.styleSheets` property.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.styleSheets

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/tests/stylesheets.html